# No query results for model [App\Task]

Tags: laravel-5

I don't know why I am keep getting this error , I am only creating new page !!!

```
Route::get('/task/create', 'TaskController@create');
```

this is the route for creating new task

```
public function create()
{
    return view('create');
}
```

this is the method that return the view

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

  ... some content

@endsection
```

this is the create file

when I try to access the page I get this error

> NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 131:
>   No query results for model [App\Task].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use App\Task;
```

At the top of your controller file.

and 2nd thing your query is wrong thats why it shown error.

Comment: already have the use statement, I didn't get it can you explain " your query is wrong " ?

Comment: your view file placed in which folder? and also name of view file?

Comment: return view('create'); it will return the view file name

Comment: i will easily resolve your issue please share your ftp details

Comment: resources/views/create.blade.php

Comment: actually it's a localhost :)

Comment: add me on skype: harryr891 and share your screen

Answer (score 6):

For Laravel the order of the routes matters. Routes with dynamic segments like tasks/{id} should always be defined after the static ones (like tasks/create) because Laravel will interpret the 'create' part in your URL as an {id}, hence your error.

Probabily you have the routes ordered like this:

```
Route::get('tasks/{task}','TasksController@show');
Route::get('tasks/create','TasksController@create');
```

Instead the 'tasks/create' route should be above:

```
Route::get('tasks/create','TasksController@create');
Route::get('tasks/{task}','TasksController@show');
```